# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined error for 1 function

Tags: javascript, html

I think it's a very common problem but I've a code like this:

```js
function add(num1, num2) {
  return num1 + num2;
}

function hello() {
  return "Hello";
}
window.alert("Num1 + Num2 = " + add(10, 5));

window.alert(hello());
```

The thing is, add() function works perfectly but try() is not. Why? I am working on Visual Studio Web Application.

Comment: `try` is a javascript keyword you need to rename your function to something that is not a js keyword

Comment: You changed your code and I see no errors

Answer (score 0):

Its becuase `try` is a reserved keyword in javascript as in `try-catch`, similarly you cannot use keywords like `let, const, var, do, for ... etc` as variable names or function declarations, change your function name to `hello` or something else and it should work perfectly fine

Comment: I did, but still having the error...

Comment: did you edit the function name in your html file too? if you did try closing and reopening your html file

Comment: Yes sir, edited the question too.

Comment: try closing and reopening your html file, and check console (f12 or ctrl + shift + i) and post the errors here, if any

Comment: Clear browser cache and try again

Comment: That actually worked! Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: Could you mark this as a correct answer please?

Answer (score 0):

That's because try is a reserved word, have you ever seen

```
try {

}catch(e){}
```

So change the name of the function, simply use try1()

Comment: I change the name sir, but still having the error.

Comment: Clear browser cache and then try